# dynamically generating factor name in lm function in R

Tags: r, lm

I have a R question here

we do the 'normal' `lm` fit quite often:

```
model <- lm(y~0+x1+x2+x3, data=d)
```

However, what I am trying to do is to select the names of `x1`, `x2`, `x3` dynamically in the R script. depending on which `y` I am fitting, the function can be run in the form of

```
model<-lm(y2~0+x10+x21+x33, data=d)

model<-lm(y3~0+x41+x15+x8, data=d)
```

etc. Please note that `y2`, `y3` ... are sequentially selected from a list. There is actually a function

```
factorOfInterest <-getFactors(y)
```

Anyone knows how to program R script like this? Or, is there a better way to construct the problem?

Comment: Create the formula using `paste` and `as.formula`. Note that if the RHS is equal you could fit models for several `yi` at once by passing them as a matrix to `lm`.

Answer (score 0):

Say your data looks like this:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(5),
                  x2=rnorm(5),
                  x3=rnorm(5),
                  y1=rnorm(5),
                  y2=rnorm(5)
                  )
```

The following will go through all combinations of the `x`s, 7 in total:

```
###  get columns named x
c1 <- colnames(df1)[grepl("x",colnames(df1))]
### make matrix of all combinations
library(combinat)
c2 <- combinat::hcube(rep(2, length(c1)))-1
###  remove top row (represents intercept-only model)
c2 <- c2[-1, ]
### list to store results
l1 <- as.list(vector(length=nrow(c2)))
### use matrix for y values when fitting models
lhs1 <- cbind(df1$y1, df1$y2)
for (i in 1:nrow(c2)){
### subset of x variables
    rhs1 <- c1[as.logical(c2[i, ])]
    rhs1 <- paste0(rhs1, collapse="+")
    f1 <- paste("lhs1", rhs1, sep="~")
    f1 <- as.formula(f1)
    l1[[i]] <- lm(f1)
}
```

(I'm sure faster methods are available for larger sets)...